# special form of a paired design (very small, unbalaned)

Tags: experiment-design, error, small-sample

I am trying to figure out how to analyze following design.

Suppose three samples are taken from the starting material of an experiment which will be performed at larger scale (LS). The same experimental procedure is applied but at smaller scale for each of the three samples. This process is repeated three times with different starting materials (same material, different lots). In total, 3 experiments at larger scale and 9 experiments at smaller scale.

[raw material set 1] -> [Large scale lot 1] -> [sample 1, sample 2, sample 3]

[raw material set 2] -> [Large scale lot 2] -> [sample 4, sample 5, sample 6]

[raw material set 3] -> [Large scale lot 2] -> [sample 7, sample 8, sample 9]

each raw material set consists of a mixture of raw materials (e.g. same type of flour from same supplier but with varying quality).

```
for each large scale lot:
    process according to an experimental procedure

for each sample:
   perform same experimental procedure as for large scale lot
```

I would like to get a rough estimate of the difference between large and small scale (I know, sample size is very low).
I have seen people calculating the difference in various ways and I do not like either of those. E.g. pooling small scale and large scale data, treating each data point as independent (which they are not if  if the quality of raw material influences the results). Another one calculated 9 paired differences and treated those as independent.
Another option would be to calculate the mean for each of the three small scale experiments and subsequently 3 paired differences (which I would prefer). But probably no one would like it because suddenly they have 3 data points instead of 9. Also, I do not know how to deal with the fact, that no uncertainty can be calculated for the large scale lots (LS).

I cannot find any information on such a design. Does it have a name or an equivalent maybe from agriculture? What would be a good way of calculating the difference between scales (large and small scale) plus error estimate in the case of those few samples?
What would you suggest, to optimize knowledge gain with minimal effort? Problem is, those experiments at large scale are really expensive and it is not feasible to produce more lots at large scale.

Comment: The experiment design is not clear, at least not to me. I find this sentence confusing: "This process is repeated three times with different starting materials (same material, different lots)." Can you update the first paragraph to clarify: how many materials, how many lots, how many samples, etc. And also, what do you measure as the outcome of each replicate? Is the outcome from a small sample comparable to the outcome from a large sample?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to explain it better.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Are both the large and small experiments taken from the same raw materials: [raw material set 1] -> [large sample 1-1, small sample 1-1, small sample 1-2, small sample 1-3], or is each small sample somehow a component of the large scale lot?